# What does the given bash script do?

Tags: bash, scripting

Can someone explain me how does the following script functions?

```
#!/bin/sh
until who | grep "$1" > /dev/null
do
   sleep 60
done
#now ring the bell and announce the expected user
echo -e '\a'
echo "*** $1 just logged in ***"
exit 0
```

Comment: You should say what is not clear, what you DID understand.

Answer (score 3):

This script waits until the command `who` (which gives out the currently logged in users) gives out a line which matches the first argument to the script, then it will ring the bell and print out a message about the user who logged in.

You should call it as

```
 script alfe
```

then it will wait until `alfe` logs in, then beep once and print `*** alfe just logged on ***`.

Comment: While this answer is mostly correct (+1), I would say (rather nit-pick), that the script _polls_, not _waits_. If the user logs in and logs out between those 60 seconds, the script will not catch it... If you really want to log every such login, consider adding a logging mechanism in your `bashrc` files (`/etc/bashrc`, `~/.bashrc`)...

Comment: @anishsane Of course you are right, but these are implementational details concerning the vague word "wait". While I meant it in the way of "wait by polling (with all its aspects like putting unnecessary load on the host and maybe skipping events)" you have more the meaning of wait(2) in mind. Mine was more the real world meaning (consider telling someone to wait until the doctor arrives; if the doctor arrives and immediately leaves again, a typical response would be to still wait for the doctor to arrive again, like polling).  Since the Q wasn't fitting SO anyway, I chose a brief explanation.

Comment: Oh no, I was only being pedantic. Just wanted to point to OP that the method is not reliable 100% times.